# Split string keeping delimiter in the same key value

Tags: php, split

I'm trying to split a string [F][C][Fa][Co] by the delimiter "]" and I want to keep it in the same value.

I'm having a problem since it keeps the delimiter but in another array field.

My Code:

```
$str = '[F][C][Fa][Co]';
$result = preg_split('/([\]])/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
var_dump( $result);
```

Expected Result:

```
$array[0] = [F]
$array[1] = [C]
$array[2] = [Fa]
$array[3] = [Co]
```

What I'm getting:

```
array(9) { [0]=> string(2) "[F" [1]=> string(1) "]" [2]=> string(2) "[C" [3]=> string(1) "]" [4]=> string(3) "[Fa" [5]=> string(1) "]" [6]=> string(3) "[Co" [7]=> string(1) "]" [8]=> string(0) "" }
```

How can I make the delimiter goes to each value?

Comment: `preg_split('/\[\w+\]\K/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);`

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works like a charm :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But you don't want to split. You want to match.

```
preg_match_all('/\[\w+\]/',$str,$matches);
var_dump($matches[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I’d use @Niet’s method, here’s how to fix yours:

You need a [lookbehind](https://regular-expressions.mobi/lookaround.html?wlr=1) (or zero width assertion), and the `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` flag to get rid of the last empty element:

```
<?php
$str = '[F][C][Fa][Co]';
$result = preg_split('/(?<=\])/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
var_dump( $result);
```

**Result**

> array(4) {   [0]=>   string(3) "[F]"   [1]=>   string(3) "[C]"   [2]=>
>   string(4) "[Fa]"   [3]=>   string(4) "[Co]" }

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/n6daB)